# How to create a multiclass dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['I am a bear', 'Animal'], ['I am a bird', 'Bird'], ['I am a Bat', 'Animal'],['I am a Bat', 'Bird']]),
                   columns=['Title', 'Task'])



    Title         Task
0   I am a bear   Animal
1   I am a bird   Bird
2   I am a Bat    Animal
3   I am a Bat    Bird
```

As the class label is different for the same input ('I am a Bat'), it is a multiclass classification task. My current approach is to group the duplicates and then add a new column with all the labels but this appears to be a tedious task. Is there a more Pythonic way of doing this?

**Edit**
Expected Output:

```
    Title         Label1 (Animal)   Label2 (Bird)
0   I am a bear   1                     0 
1   I am a bird   0                     1
2   I am a Bat    1                     1
```

Comment: pls add your expected output from the given dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `crosstab()`:

```
df=pd.crosstab(df['Title'],df['Task']).rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index()
```

output of `df`:

```
    Title       Animal  Bird
0   I am a Bat      1   1
1   I am a bear     1   0
2   I am a bird     0   1
```

**OR**

If needed in your expected output format use:

```
df=pd.crosstab(df['Title'],df['Task'])
df.columns=[f"Label{x} ({y})" for x,y in enumerate(df.columns,1)]
df=df.rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index()
```

output of `df`:

```
    Title       Label1 (Animal)     Label2 (Bird)
0   I am a Bat      1               1
1   I am a bear     1               0
2   I am a bird     0               1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this as an alternate to `pd.crosstab` as suggested by @Anurag Dabas-

```
pd.get_dummies(df.set_index(['Title'])).groupby(level=0).sum().reset_index()
```

```
         Title  Task_Animal  Task_Bird
0   I am a Bat            1          1
1  I am a bear            1          0
2  I am a bird            0          1
```

You can rename the columns after that.

Explanation:

1. Set 'Title' as index
2. Use `pd.get_dummies` to one-hot encode the 2 columns
3. Groupby sum over the index to combine the counts/flags
4. `reset_index` to get back the index as column 'Title'